# Retrieve radio button value from groupbox

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

I have 3 radio buttons in a groupbox. I have coded what I thought was correct, but the event only works on one radio button. For example, rdbServiceStandard if clicked displays a value for rbServicePermanent which is 'P', where it should be displaying 'S' and sometimes it dosen't fire at all. I guess my question is, have I coded correctly to retrieve values from radio buttons is a groupbox. Many thanks

**groupbox**

gbxServiceLevel

**radio buttons**

rdbServiceStandard

rbServicePermant

rdbServiceRapid

**Variable to hold value**

rbServiceLevel

```
Private Sub gbxServiceLevel_Enter(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles gbxServiceLevel.Enter
        If rdbServiceStandard.Checked Then
            rbServiceLevel = "S"
        ElseIf rdbServiceRapid.Checked Then
            rbServiceLevel = "R"
        ElseIf rdbServicePermanent.Checked Then
            rbServiceLevel = "P"
        End If
        MessageBox.Show(rbServiceLevel)
    End Sub
```

Comment: is it rbServicePermant or rdbServicePermant?

Comment: Thank you Ash. Corrected. My typo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
If CType(sender, RadioButton).Checked Then

    Select Case Ctype(sender,radiobutton).Name
        Case "rdbServiceStandard"
            If rdbServiceStandard.Checked Then rbServiceLevel = "S"
        Case "rdbServiceRapid"
            If rdbServiceRapid.Checked Then rbServiceLevel = "R"
        Case Else 'rdbServicePermanent
            If rdbServicePermanent.Checked Then rbServiceLevel = "P"
    End Select

    MessageBox.Show(rbServiceLevel)
End If
```

The issue is that option (radio) button groups get the CheckChanged event **twice**: once when the old selection is UNCHECKED and once when it is CHECKED, so to capture just the act of the user selecting an option, respond when the sender state is Checked.  Without the CHECK test, you will get the msgbox twice.

You can use the `Tag` property to shorted the code.  Set the Tag property for eacd radiobutton to the corresponding code (e.g. `rdbServiceStandard` would be "S").  Then the code is just:

```
' this is just to prevent 2 CType statements
Dim thisRB As RadioButton = CType(sender, RadioButton).Checked 

If rb.Checked Then
    rbServiceLevel = thisRB.Tag
End If
```

Second, if `I first enter the form and click the first option rdbServiceStandard, which is default, it shows 'S' which is fine`: if you have to Click the first option to select it, then it is not a default - the default would be the option which **starts out** already selected when the form opens.

Third, if the first really is a default, the CheckChanged event will fire when the form loads and VB/NET sets the default to checked.  This is often no big deal - it would just be setting the `rbServiceLevel` to the default.  But if you have action code in the event like a MsgBox, it will run as well.

Comment: Thanks very much Plutonix. To the rescue as usual :-)

Answer (score 1):

I find it easier to manipulate the radiobuttons checkedchanged event rather than the Groupbox's Enter event:

```
Private Sub RadioButton_CheckedChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles rdbServiceStandard.CheckedChanged, rdbServiceRapid.CheckedChanged, rdbServicePermanent.CheckedChanged
        Select Case Ctype(sender,radiobutton).Name
            Case "rdbServiceStandard"
                If rdbServiceStandard.Checked Then rbServiceLevel = "S"
            Case "rdbServiceRapid"
                If rdbServiceRapid.Checked Then rbServiceLevel = "R"
            Case Else 'rdbServicePermanent
                If rdbServicePermanent.Checked Then rbServiceLevel = "P"
        End Select

        MessageBox.Show(rbServiceLevel)
    End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks Ruben. However, something strange is happening. When I first enter the form and click the first option rdbServiceStandard, which is default, it shows 'S' which is fine, but if click the next button, rdbServiceRapid it still shows 'S'.